# Backspace/delete produces a font element in chrome browser

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a javascript project
I have a div tag which contains text:

`<div> your text here! </div>`

When I do a **Backspace** and I delete all the text **(character by character)**
With the last backspace, I lose the `<div>` tag and a `<br>` tag that displays,
After if I want to add text, a FONT tag that appears

**`<font face = "ArialNORMAL"> <span style = "font-size: 16px;"> a link </span> </font>`**

I saw this behavior only with the Chrome browser: Version 85.0.4183.102 (Official build) (64 bits)

My question is where does the tag come from and what do I do to prevent its creation?

Comment: Are you using `contenteditable`?

Comment: Can you show us a working example of your bug/code?

Comment: @Pardal : Yes, i used contenteditable

Comment: @Roberrrt : I will explain to you in a next comment